# Is it possible to create new projects in Basecamp via their API?

Tags: api, project-management, basecamp

Using the [Basecamp API](http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/companies.shtml), is it possible to create a new project? It seems like a simple task, so either I'm missing something or this functionality is not available via the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't explicitly say you can't, I found another link that says it's not possible here:

http://groups.google.com/group/37signals-api/browse_thread/thread/71557a03aa11c6f4?pli=1

This kinda makes sense if you think about it - adding new projects could take you over your account limits etc. there is probably a licensing/billing agreement you need to physically consent to.

Comment: I saw that post also. I was hoping someone had found an alternate solution or some other workaround. Oh well. It seems adding new projects just isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2012 the new Basecamp API allows you to create projects using JSON. See [here](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/projects.md).